# Import variable from python script to jupyter ipython notebook

Tags: python, variables, jupyter-notebook, sharing

I am newbie to python and searched for 2 days to get solution but could not get find any solution. Please help me.

I have two python(newkmeans.py,newbisecting.py) files and one ipython jupyter notebook. I am running newbiecting.py from ipython notebook by calling it as %newbisecting.py which in turn calls newkmeans.py file. Now newkmeans.py file generates few set of variables like for example list values list1. I want to access this list1[] in ipython jupyter notebook. How can I do this? Please help me out.

I have tried using from newkmeans import list1 in ipython juypter notebook but could not get any results.

Comment: can you share some code @somesh-pulikanti

Comment: code somehat looks like this :    if __name__=="__main__": runkmeans()  . This runkmean() function contains  def runkmeans():  %run newtest_bisecting.py.  newtestbisecting.py looks like this :#!/bin/env python3
import argparse

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from newkmeans import BisectingKMeansClusterer, KMeansClusterer
 c = BisectingKMeansClusterer(
        data, max_k=args.max_k, min_gain=args.min_gain, verbose=args.verbose). This calls newkmeans.py script which has list1 variable. Now I need to access this list1 in jupyter notebook where my main() is present.